# radio button in ionic with angular doest limit one selection per group

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

ion-radio (radio buttons) doesnt work properly when integrated with angular for loop to generate options dynamically.
Although the radio buttons are visible, the option selection is not limited to one per group. 
multi selection is allowed which is not the expected behavior of radio button.

Sample use of radio button from documentation that works as expected

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-radio-group>
    <ion-list-header>
      <ion-label>Name</ion-label>
    </ion-list-header>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Biff</ion-label>
      <ion-radio slot="start" value="biff" checked></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Griff</ion-label>
      <ion-radio slot="start" value="griff"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Buford</ion-label>
      <ion-radio slot="start" value="buford"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-radio-group>
</ion-list>
```

Generation options dynamically with angular that doesnt work as expected

```
<div *ngFor="let item of quiz; let i = index">
  <ion-list >
    <ion-radio-group>
      <ion-list-header>
        <ion-label>{{item.quiz_question}}</ion-label>
      </ion-list-header>
      <div *ngFor="let option of item.quiz_option; let z = index">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>{{option.quiz_option_txt}}</ion-label>
        <ion-radio slot="start" value="biff"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
      </div>
    </ion-radio-group>
  </ion-list>
</div>
```

Allow just one option selection per group.

Comment: You have to assign the property `name` to them. Assign same name to all radios in a group

Answer (score 0):

This is because your aren't using different "values" in **ion-radio**. Try to do this:

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let item of quiz; let i = index">
    <ion-radio-group>
        <ion-list-header>
            <ion-label>{{item.quiz_question}}</ion-label>
        </ion-list-header>

        <ion-item *ngFor="let option of item.quiz_option; let z = index">
            <ion-label>{{option.quiz_option_txt}}</ion-label>
            <ion-radio slot="start" [value]="z"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>

    </ion-radio-group>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Thanks, it was because of the values. Is there any particular reason that the radio must have different values set?

Comment: Yes, the "value" from ion-radio will be your "response" to your quiz to save on database or publish.